# Ruby-on-Rails: Help with render: layout => false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, render, actionpack

I am trying to access a rails app resource from an API (it sends an Application/XML GET request) and I would like to not have to parse the XML file.

In my resources controller I have the following:

```
def get_resource
    @my_resource = Resources.new
    render :xml => @my_resource
end
```

which produces an xml file as expected. If i replace it with:

```
render :layout => false
```

my API reports a "template missing" error. I've also tried the following:

```
render :xml => @identity, :layout => false
```

But the page renders anyway. What's the right way to go about this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you render :xml, it does not use a layout because it doesn't use any template either. By specifying :layout => false, you tell rails to look for a template which does not exist.

Now, if you don't want to parse an xml file, then you have a few alternatives. Either:

```
render :json => @my_resource
```

or

```
render :text => "My resource name is: #{@my_resource.name}" # Whatever you want
```

It all depends on how you want the result to look, what your API expects to receive. So if you don't find any of this helpful, give an example of how you want the response to look.

Comment: There's also always `render nothing: true`

Answer (score 4):

```
def get_resource
  @my_resource = Resources.new
  respond_to do |wants|
    wants.xml { render :xml => @my_resource }
    wants.html { render :layout => false }
  end
end
```

Read this article: http://tokumine.wordpress.com/2009/09/13/how-does-respond_to-work-in-the-rails-controllers/

Comment: That link is dead. Here is the new one: http://tokumine.wordpress.com/2009/09/13/how-does-respond_to-work-in-the-rails-controllers/